# Zend_Db_Select - Get all selected tables and columns

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

We are using the Zend Framework in our company and thus we're using Zend_Db_Select.

Now we are building a query with it which is then (pre fetch) passed to a function.
The query is built as follows:

```
$select = $this->_selectAll()
                    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                    ->joinLeft('shop', $conShop, $colShop)
                    ->joinLeft('ptool', $conPtool, $colPtool)
                    ->where('ptool.product_id > 0')
                    ->where('ptool.product_is_from_shop = 0')
                    ;
```

Where $conShop and $colShop are something like:

```
$colShop = array('shop_id','shop_channel');
$conShop = "shop.shop_id = ptool.shop_id";
```

In a new method I want to get all joined tables and their columns that are going to be selected. So the $select gets passed to the method and now I would like to get something like this:

```
Array
(
    ['shop'] => Array 
    (
        [0] => 'shop_id',
        [1] => 'shop_channel',
        ...

    ),
    ['ptool'] => Array 
    (
        [0] => 'shop_id',
        [1] => 'ptool_id',
        ...

    ),
    ...
)
```

It would be nice if I can get this pre fetch.

The background is that I want to sort by shop_id for example and this table name is used in two joined tables. If I do something like "ORDER BY shop_id" I'd get the error that the column is ambiguous. That's why I need to know which columns belong to which table so that I can do something like "ORDER BY shop.shop_id"

Hope you can help me. Thanks! :)

Comment: If you please provide some code then we can help you

Comment: Hey, what code would be helpful? I'll add a bit.

Comment: have you check what query `$select` returns ? `echo $select;`